# Is there a way to manage multiple domains on a single Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, devops

I work with a dev shop as a contractor & I'm pitching Kubernetes to my CTO.

It's on the premise that they can deploy multiple websites and abstract away multi-server management.

However, the one stipulation is that in this new cluster of resources they would be able to point multiple different domains at it and still be able to route requests accordingly.

So my question is: how can i manage multiple domains on a single Kubernetes cluster?

I don't know if this sort of thing is possible in Kubernetes, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an ingress with multiple domain names:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

In the `rules` section, you can define multiple hosts like:

```
rules:
  - host: host1.com
    http:
      paths:
      ...
  - host: host2.com
    http:
      paths:
       ...
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Would I then use DNS to point those domain names to the cluster IP?

Comment: You point the DNS to the ingress. How that is done depends on how you expose the ingress. A nodeport,  a load balancer, etc.